# How mark a .NET Web API Regex Route Parameter as optional

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Microsoft explains that you can do optional attribute routing here: [Optional Attribute Routing for Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional), simply by adding a '?' to the end of the parameter.

I have a regex parameter, but I am having trouble setting the parameter as optional. The regex works fine, but **as soon as I start trying to work out how to mark it as optional, the constraint resolver chokes.**

```
[Route(@"{id:long}/terminate/{terminationDate:regex('^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$)}")]
```

Removing the string literal allows the optional but seems to break the regex:

```
[Route("{id:long}/terminate/{terminationDate:regex('^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$)?}")]
```

More plainly I want to achieve:

> /123456/terminate/2021-11-12

**OR**

> /123456/terminate/

Am I just trying to escape this incorrectly?

Comment: You could start with your original rule, remove the string literal, test your escaped rule, add the optional specifier.

Comment: Please, can you show the action signature?